# Powershell Job "Completed" but did not finish it's task

Tags: powershell, start-job

I am trying to start/stop services via a job in powershell. In testing this on my local machine, the job will go to a completed state but the service will not change its status. Is there a way to get a better view of what my job did?

Here is the code:

```
$service = 'MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS'
$server = 'myPC'
$myJob = Start-Job -Scriptblock {Get-Service -Name $args[0] -computername $args[1] | Set-Service -Status Running} -ArgumentList @($service,$server)
sleep -Seconds 10
get-job
```

The SQL SQL (EXPRESS) service does not start when I run that snippet.

However, if I ran the following from the elevated shell, it would start:

```
Get-Service -Name $service -computername $server | Set-Service -Status Running
```

When I run Get-Job, here is what I see...

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command                  
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------                  
10     Job10           BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost            Get-Service -Name $arg...
```

These are both running from an elevated shell, so I definitely have permission to start/stop the service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Get-Job | Receive-Job` to see the output from your jobs (including any errors).

Or (to be more specific) for the job you created:

```
$myjob | Receive-Job
```

Also FYI, rather than `Start-Sleep`, you could do `$myjob | Wait-Job` to wait for the job to complete before continuing code execution. You can also:

```
$myjob | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find that my issue was "get-service : Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer. This operation might require other
privileges.". Strange that the job would still go to a completed state with such an error. But thanks for the answer!